# How do I format a date within R?

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to initialize a date variable with formatting to gain the type of date format of 20:

```
upload_date <- as.Date("2017/12/1", format = '%y/%m/%d')
```

Once that line of code runs, I receive the following output:

```
> str(upload_date) 
Date[1:1], format: NA
```

Can someone detail how to properly format a date within R?  Thank you.

Comment: As the answer below shows, you are using an incorrect year format. %y is the year without the century. %Y is the four-digit year. The links are in the help - the format codes themselves are in the help for the base function 
strptime, linked to the as.Date help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
upload_date <- as.Date("2017/12/1", format = '%Y/%m/%d')
```